# Split dataframe into several ones (not the same size) based on consecuvite zero values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, split

i have a dataframe with numeric values (i show here only the column used for the "condition").
I would like splitting it into several others (the size of the splitted dataframes could be different). The "splitting" should be based on consecutive no zero values.

In the following case from this initial dataframe:

[image: me]:

I would like these three dataframes into new variables

[image: first], [image: second],[image: third]

Is there any function to achieve that without parsing all the initial dataframe?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think i found the solution...

```
df['index']=df.index.values                #Create columns with index
s = df.iloc[:,3].eq(0)                     #mask of zero value
new_df = df.groupby([s, s.cumsum()]).apply(lambda x: list(x.index)) #find on stackoverflow to group value based on the previous mask
out=new_df.loc[False]                      #Select only False Value therefore only value >0
```

Finally i have a dataframe with the group of index of consecutive non zero values